# Make a vector of distribution parameter estimates

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

What I want to do is to predict a bunch of parameters using MLEs, and then make a vector of this information. I tried to use the following command:

```
Table[EstimatedDistribution[
  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.1], 5], 
  ExponentialDistribution[a]], {i, 5}]
```

However, this simply returns a vector as follows:

```
{ExponentialDistribution[0.0541708], 
 ExponentialDistribution[0.148346], 
 ExponentialDistribution[0.0801585], ExponentialDistribution[0.109], 
 ExponentialDistribution[0.101503]}
```

But I'm looking for it to instead return:

```
{0.0541708, 0.148346, 0.0801585, 0.109, 0.101503}
```

How could I go about pulling out those parameters and placing them in this vector format? Or is there possibly a better in-built function I could be using?

Comment: `Table[a /. FindDistributionParameters[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.1], 5], ExponentialDistribution[a]], {5}]`. This is of course in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine this with [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html):

```
data = 
 Table[First@
   EstimatedDistribution[
    RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.1], 5], 
    ExponentialDistribution[a]], {i, 5}]
(* {0.0662656, 0.121466, 0.108902, 0.0871212, 0.0922651} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

`EstimatedDistribution` finds the distribution, from which you'd have to extract the parameters. Use `FindDistributionParameters` instead to obtain the parameters directly:

```
a /. Table[
  FindDistributionParameters[
   RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.1], 5], 
   ExponentialDistribution[a]
   ]
  , {i, 5}]
```

> {0.0504677, 0.0848974, 0.0631045, 0.132201, 0.07284}